# Lxml get text in div element which comes after another one

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following example code.

```
<div class="first">Text1</div><div class="second">Text2</div>
```

How can I get 'Text2' with Lxml library?

Thanks.

Comment: More document context is needed. You may be able to write an xpath that ends with `div[2]/text()` or maybe use the `following-sibling` axis. Perhaps even `div[@class="second"]/text()`. It depends on the surrounding context of the document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `following-sibling::div[1]` to get the nearest `div` element that come after another element, for example :

```
from lxml import etree

source = '''<root>
<div class="first">Text1</div><div class="second">Text2</div>
</root>'''
root = etree.fromstring(source)
result = root.xpath("//div[@class='first']/following-sibling::div[1]/text()")
print(result)
```

**output :**

```
['Text2']
```

Or maybe you can directly identify the target element by it's class, like so :

```
result = root.xpath("//div[@class='second']/text()")
```